# Changing DB query for specific user

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In our project, we are using spring, JPA & hibernate over Mysql.
I have a DB table that contains permissions per each user. this table has a lot of implications all over the system.
I need to add a "super user" / admin, that has permissions for everything.
I want that every query that made by this admin user - will "simulate" like the permissions table contains permissions to this admin user.

For example:
The DB table is -

```
entityId | userId
```

If we have 2 entities, and user#17 has permissions to them, the rows would be

```
1 | 17
2 | 17
```

Lets say the admin user is user#20. I don't want to add rows to this table. I want that every access to this table will add "temporary rows".
For example, if I have the following query:

```
select e from MyEntity e where e.id in (select p.entityId from PermissionEntity p where p.userId = :userId)
```

I want that if the logged in user is admin user, the query will look like:

```
select e from MyEntity e where e.id in (select p.entityId from PermissionEntity p)
```

or

```
select e from MyEntity e where e.id in (select p.entityId from PermissionEntity p where 1=1 or p.userId = :userId)
```

Any advice how to implement this?

Comment: Hibernate has the notion of [filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch19.html#objectstate-filters) which you can use to have the clause added to the query dynamically. We did this successfully in one of our projects. For normal users the data was limited to what they could see, for admins we simply didn't add the additional clause.

Comment: Another option would be to use Spring Security instead of database filters. You could use Spring Security to apply ACL to your objects. Although it can be a pain to setup and might be a performance hit when you have large result sets.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a central method where you check the rights. If so, simply try:

```
TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = null;
if (crtUser.getId() != 20) {
    query = entityManager.createQuery("select e from MyEntity e where e.id in (select p.entityId from PermissionEntity p p.userId = :userId)", MyEntitiy.class);
}
else {
    query = entityManager.createQuery("select e from MyEntity e", MyEntitiy.class);
}
```

If you don't have a central method for this logic, but have a single method, then you could try the following:

```
    query = entityManager.createQuery("select e from MyEntity e where e.id in (select p.entityId from PermissionEntity p p.userId = :userId) OR :userId=20", MyEntitiy.class);
```

Comment: No, we don't have central place. If we had one, I wouldn't have ask this question :)